# Are there strictly dominated strategies?

Tags: game-theory, dominant-strategy

Two players simultaneously announce a prime number less than 20.Denoting $p_{i}$ the number announced by the player $i$, the payoffs are:

-If $p_{1}+p_{2}<14$ each player receives as payment the value of $p_{i}+1$.

-If $p_{1}+p_{2} \geq{14}$ and $p_{i}<p_{j}$, player $i$ receives $p_{j}$ and the player $j$ receive $20-p_{i}$.

-If $p_{1}+p_{2} \geq{14}$ and $p_{i}=p_{j}$, each player receives a payoff $p_{i}$.

Q1:My game in normal form is correct?

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & 2 & 3&5&7&11&13&17&19 \\ \hline
2&3,3& 3,4&3,6 & 3,8&3,12&13,18&17,18&19,18\\ \hline
3 & 4,3 & 4,4& 4,5&4,8&11,17&13,17&17,17&19,17\\ \hline
 5& 6,3 & 6,4& 6,6&6,8&11,15&13,15&17,15&19,15\\ \hline 
7& 8,3 & 8,4& 8,6&7,7&11,13&13,13&17,13&19,13\\ \hline 
11& 12,3 & 17,11& 15,11&13,11&11,11&13,9&17,9&19,9\\ \hline 
13& 18,13 & 17,13& 15,13&13,13&9,13&13,13&17,7&19,7\\ \hline 
17& 18,17 & 17,17& 15,17&13,17&9,17&7,17&17,17&19,3\\ \hline 
19& 18,19 & 17,19& 15,19&13,19&9,19&7,19&3,19&19,19\\ \hline 
\end{array}

Q2:There are strictly dominated strategies?
For the table, I think not. Is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: The game looks correct (I only checked a few cells though). Based on the matrix, there is no strictly dominated strategy, mainly because of the last row/column.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Herr, the payoff matrix looks right. Also, there are no strictly dominated strategies because a strictly dominated strategy cannot be a best response for any possible belief. However, If any player believes that the other player is choosing 19, then every strategy (both pure and mixed) is a best response.

Answer (score 1):

**Q1**

Your table seems to be correct. Here is a quick Python implementation for generating the payoffs:

```
def payoff_calculator(x, y):
    if x+y < 14:
        return (x+1,y+1)
    else:
        if x==y:
            return (x,y)
        else:
            return (y,20-x) if x < y else (20-y,x)

primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
payoffs = [[payoff_calculator(i,j) for i in primes] for j in primes]

for row in payoffs:
    print(*row)
```

**Result**

```
(3, 3) (4, 3) (6, 3) (8, 3) (12, 3) (18, 13) (18, 17) (18, 19)
(3, 4) (4, 4) (6, 4) (8, 4) (17, 11) (17, 13) (17, 17) (17, 19)
(3, 6) (4, 6) (6, 6) (8, 6) (15, 11) (15, 13) (15, 17) (15, 19)
(3, 8) (4, 8) (6, 8) (7, 7) (13, 11) (13, 13) (13, 17) (13, 19)
(3, 12) (11, 17) (11, 15) (11, 13) (11, 11) (9, 13) (9, 17) (9, 19)
(13, 18) (13, 17) (13, 15) (13, 13) (13, 9) (13, 13) (7, 17) (7, 19)
(17, 18) (17, 17) (17, 15) (17, 13) (17, 9) (17, 7) (17, 17) (3, 19)
(19, 18) (19, 17) (19, 15) (19, 13) (19, 9) (19, 7) (19, 3) (19, 19)
```

**Q2**

You are right, there are no strictly dominated strategies here. This is because each action is a best response to some opponent action. For example, 2 is a best response to opponent moves 13, 17, and 19, 3 is a best response to 11, 13, 17, and 19, and so on. Similarly, there is no strictly dominant strategy. For example, 19 is a best response to 2, 3, 5, 7, and 19, but not to 11, 13, or 17.